# Does reducing the amount of carb intake increase the anti-inflammatory effect of turmeric curcumin?

Tags: nutrition, tendinitis

I read the following claim from a company selling turmeric curcumin pills (also containing Ginger, Boswellia & BioPerine), to optimize the anti-inflammatory effect of the pills:

> TIP - Cut down on sugar and carbs
>
> It's not popular to recommend and it’s not easy to make a lifestyle
>   change, but it makes a MAJOR difference. At the very least I recommend
>   you cut down on sugar and carbs dramatically for the first couple
>   weeks. This will allow the product to quickly get to work without
>   being bogged down fighting new inflammation.

The pills contains turmeric curcumin, Ginger, Boswellia & BioPerine:

[image]

Is there evidence confirming or infirming that reducing the amount of carb intake increases the anti-inflammatory effect of turmeric curcumin? I'm mostly interested in tendinitises.